# Is there any conversion mechanism of neutron radiation into electromagnetic radiation?

Tags: electromagnetism, particle-physics, nuclear-physics, neutrons

Charged radiation such as beta, alpha or even stray protons and nuclei as they are charged can loose their energy as photons. Can neutrons do this as well, even if they do not have any electric charge through any method?

Comment: Create an excited nucleus (through absorption, induced fission, or various n,* reactions) and release a gamma?

Answer (score 1):

Neutrons can shed energy as electromagnetic waves, but the process is indirect, as follows:

The neutrons flying out of a reactor can get stopped by the shielding in the reactor walls by inelastically scattering off the nuclei in the atoms comprising the shielding. Those shielding atoms are thus caused to vibrate i.e., the walls get hot, and begin to radiate infrared light.

FYI in power reactors intended to run on *fusion*, the huge neutron flux produced is intended to be caught by a component inside the reactor called *the first wall* where the kinetic energy of the neutrons is converted into heat, which boils water into steam to power a turbogenerator.

(Note that the gamma rays given off by nuclear reactions also get scattered inelastically in the shielding and get converted into heat as well.)

Comment: Is there any method by which the neutrons kinetic energy can be converted to photons, like in Bremsstrahlung, directly? Neutrons do not have charge so this would not be possible, but this is what I had in mind when asking this question.

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming you are talking about kinetic energy.

Fast moving electrons and protons can emit photons in magnetic fields or by interacting with other charged particles, but not in empty space. Uncharged particles cannot do this

Comment: However, neutrons have a spin magnetic moment. Couldn't this property be used?

Answer (score 0):

Neutrons in addition to being neutral, have a lifetime of about 13 minutes, that is why neutron radiation is the problem in shielding. Neutrons and gamma rays produced in reactors copiously, as neutral can penetrate a lot of shielding matter :

If there were a way,it would have been used instead of shielding, as the objective of reactors is to convert radiation to heat. Eventually the energy of the neutrals becomes heat in the shielding, through collisions with atoms and molecules (these collisions  might produce radiation), but not in an [economically  a usable form.](https://www.energy.gov/ne/articles/nuclear-101-how-does-nuclear-reactor-work) Example:

> [The X-10 reactor was constructed of graphite](https://www.mne.k-state.edu/%7Ejks/papers/HPreview.pdf) and was air cooled. Its shielding was 2.1-m-thick made of baryte and haydite concretes, baryte being of high density and haydite being high in hydrogen content. This shielding also was adequate for gamma rays and over designed for neutrons